# Bi-directional unique key constraint for combination of two columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the below table columns in MySQL.

```
id
user_primary_email
user_secondary_email
```

I want to make the combination of columns `user_primary_email` and `user_secondary_email` unique which I can achieve by using `UNIQUE KEY unique_key_name (user_primary_email, user_secondary_email)`

The above addition of unique key constraint will help me achieve the below scenario or rather just by adding a unique key to the individual column itself.

```
user_primary_email = 'xyz@gmail.com' AND user_secondary_email = 'pqr@gmail.com'
user_primary_email = 'xyz@gmail.com' AND user_secondary_email = 'pqr@gmail.com' //This will not be allowed to enter due to unique key constraint
```

Now the problem which I am facing is the same combination should not be allowed to add in a reverse way as mentioned below.

```
user_primary_email = 'pqr@gmail.com' AND user_secondary_email = 'xyz@gmail.com' //This should not be allowed to add since already same email id combination added once

id    |   user_primary_email   |   user_secondary_email
-------------------------------------------------------
1     |   xyz@gmail.com        |   pqr@gmail.com
-------------------------------------------------------
2     |   pqr@gmail.com        |   xyz@gmail.com       
-------------------------------------------------------
```

In the above case during insert of **row id 2** it should throw error as both the email id combination is already used in **row id 1**.

Any help would be great.

Comment: check constraint? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

Comment: This will not work in this scenario.

Comment: ah, sorry i'm not sure about mysql.  I know in sql server you can write a function that has a query within it that can be placed in a check constraint... i guess the same doesn't exist for mysql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In any MariaDB:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_primary_email` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_secondary_email` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mycheck` varchar(128) AS (IF(user_primary_email<user_secondary_email,CONCAT(user_primary_email,user_secondary_email),CONCAT(user_secondary_email,user_primary_email))) PERSISTENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mycheck` (`mycheck`)
);

MariaDB [test]> insert into t values (1,'a','b',null);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into t values (2,'b','a',null);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'ab' for key 'mycheck'
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct support for that, but you can use a workaround to create your bidirectional key: You need a unique key on an ordered version of your two columns.

Fortunately, you can very easily do that. MySQL 5.7.6+ supports generated columns and unique indexes for them, which you can use to order your two values and to enforce uniqueness.

```
create table testBiDirKey (
  a varchar(100), 
  b varchar(100),
  a_ordered varchar(100) as (least(a, b)) STORED,
  b_ordered varchar(100) as (greatest(a, b)) STORED,
  unique key unqBi_test_ab (a_ordered, b_ordered)
);

insert into testBiDirKey(a,b) values('a', 'b');
insert into testBiDirKey(a,b) values('b', 'a');
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'a-b' for key 'unqBi_test_ab'
```

This will treat `null` exactly as your current normal unique key, so

```
insert into testBiDirKey(a,b) values('a', null);
insert into testBiDirKey(a,b) values('a', null);
insert into testBiDirKey(a,b) values(null, 'a');
```

are all allowed. You can add `coalesce(x,'')` to only allow one empty value (either `null` OR `''`) if you want. If you verify your values before you add them (e.g. if they don't contain a `,`), you can combine the two columns to just one, concatenated with an `,` - although with little benefit apart from just having 1 additional column.

For 5.7.8+, you don't need the `STORED` keyword anymore to be able to use these columns in an index. That keyword effects if the values are stored (using disk space) or calculated when required (default).

Before MySQL 5.7.6, you can use a trigger (on `update` and `insert`) to update the two columns with the these values, the same logic applies, it's just a little more code.

Comment: Great answer along with clear explanation...I am using MariaDB hence accepting the above answer...But upvoting your answer too as this is going to be very helpful for others...thanks